# Memory leak in a C linked-list

Tags: c, list, memory-leaks, linked-list, nodes

I'm writing a bit C code, and trying to play a bit with lists.
For some reason the following code brings me the Author, Year and ISBN of the book, but the title is missing. I suspect it's a memory leak somewhere in the "insert_at_begin" function. Although I'm really not sure what to do there. The Program reads from a file with books names, authors etc und should give it back as a dynamic list.

Any hint or some kind of help would be greatly appreciated. I did look around the internet and in stack overflow but couldn't find a solution for this memory leak. I added the relevant code, although its pretty long, I'm not sure where the leak is, so I thought it would be better like this.

```
typedef struct _element element;


typedef struct _list { 
    element *first;    
    int count;        
} list;


struct _element {
    char* title;
    char* author;
    int year;
    long long int isbn;
    element *next;
};


element *insert_at_begin(element *first, element *new_elem) {

    if(first) {
        new_elem->next = first;
        first = new_elem;

    } else {
        first = new_elem;
    }

    return first;

}


element *construct_element(char *title, char* author, int year, long long int isbn) {

    element* book = malloc(sizeof(element));
    book->title = title;
    book->author = author;
    book->year = year;
    book->isbn = isbn;
    book->next = NULL;
    return book;
}


void free_list(list *alist) {

    //Only when there is 2 elements in the list start this loops
    for (int i=1; i<alist->count; i++) {
        free(alist->first->next);
    }

    free(alist->first);
    free(alist);

}


void read_list(char* filename, list *alist) {
    element* new_elem;

    char* title;
    char* author;
    int year;
    long long int isbn;
    read_line_context ctx;
    open_file(&ctx, filename);
    while(read_line(&ctx, &title, &author, &year, &isbn) == 0) {
        new_elem = construct_element(title, author, year, isbn);
        alist->first = insert_at_begin(alist->first, new_elem);
        alist->count++;
    }
}

list* construct_list() {
    list *alist = malloc(sizeof(list));
    alist->first = NULL;
    alist->count = 0;
    return alist;
}


void print_list(list *alist) {
    printf("My Books\n================\n\n");
    int counter = 1;
    element *elem = alist->first;
    while (elem != NULL) {
        printf("Book %d\n", counter);
        printf("\tTitel: %s\n", elem->title);
        printf("\tAuthor: %s\n", elem->author);
        printf("\tYear:  %d\n", elem->year);
        printf("\tISBN:  %lld\n", elem->isbn);
        elem = elem->next;
        counter++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    list *alist = construct_list();
    read_list(argc>1?argv[1]:"buecherliste.txt", alist);
    print_list(alist);
    free_list(alist);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what will be printed, as you can see the titles are missing and some of the information is getting chopped off. I did try the X Code Leaks tool, but couldn't find anything useful there. I added a printf function for debugging in the while-loop of read_list, and there it worked perfectly. So it has to be something with the insert_at_begin function.

```
My Books
================

Book 1
    Titel: 
    Author: Phillip K. Dick
    Year:  1973
    ISBN:  9780547572178
Book 2
    Titel: 
    Author: nner Darkly
    Year:  1949
    ISBN:  9783548267456
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is the read_line function:

```
int read_line(read_line_context *ctx, char **name, char **author, int *year, long long int *isbn) {
    if (ctx->filepointer == NULL){
        perror(ctx->filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    char *name_s;
    char *author_s;
    char *year_s;
    char *isbn_s;
    char *delim = ";";
    ssize_t len;

    if ((len = getline(&(ctx->line), &(ctx->linecapp), ctx->filepointer)) != -1)
    {
        /* remove tailing newline */
        char *pos;
        if ((pos = strchr(ctx->line, '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0';

        /* read individual fields */
        name_s   = strtok(ctx->line, delim);
            author_s = strtok(NULL, delim);
        year_s   = strtok(NULL, delim);
        isbn_s   = strtok(NULL, delim);
        if(name_s != NULL && author_s != NULL && year_s != NULL  && isbn_s != NULL ) {
            *name   = name_s;
            *author = author_s;
            *year   = atoi(year_s);
            *isbn   = atoll(isbn_s);
            return 0;
        }

    }
    fclose(ctx->filepointer);
    ctx->filepointer = NULL;
    ctx->linecapp = 0;
    if (ctx->line != NULL ) {
        free(ctx->line);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Your loop inside `free_list` should probably loop on `while(ptr)` and should end with `nextptr = ptr->next; free(ptr); ptr = nextptr;`. And you should make a drawing on paper or board to understand the shape of your data structures.

Comment: Show part of `read_line`

Comment: Show us the place where you allocate the memory for the strings `title` and `author`. Your data structure only holds pointers to there - they must point to some memory area that is valid for the whole lifetime of the data structure.

Comment: Generally I'm highly against freeing and allocating memory within different functions unsafe in my opinion

Comment: @tofro That's the thing, I'm not sure where I should allocate the memory for them (dynamically). Inside the construct_element function?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I added the function

Comment: `*name   = name_s;` --> `*name   = strdup(name_s);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you haven't allocated any memory to `author` and `title`.

```
struct _element {
    char title[100];
    char author[100];
     int year;
    long long int isbn;
    element *next;
};
```

would work better but would restrict you title/author character count to 100...

so you should really use `malloc` or `calloc` to allocate the memory you need - I suggest the code above just to get the thing working on a quick and dirty basis...

Comment: But then I can't assign to them values inside the construct_element function right?

Comment: Yes you code would need to change elsewhere...  I think two points are relevant here (1) `element* book = malloc(sizeof(element));` at the moment does not allocate space for the character arrays (strings) and (2) when you import and read values in from the file you do not put them into a place where memory has been allocated. -- you need to allocate memory somewhere for `title` and `author` - I am just suggesting that you might want to start by putting it in your structure definition -- you would then probably need to use `<string.h>` functions like `strcpy` to move strings (char arrays)

Comment: Thanks! I did add fixed size for the title and author in the struct definition and in the contruct_element the following code:     `strcat(book->title, title);
    strcat(book->author, author);` Now everything shows up correctly. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Great, I hope it works out for you - IMHO the neatest solution is to first read in `author` and `title` to strings which are very long - e.g. 1000 characters - then you can measure their length and allocate just enough memory for title and author in their particular structure element to store them... but I think this is overkill.... If this question is solved for you then it would be a good idea to mark an answer (this one or another) as the solution so that people know that this question has been answered for you.

Comment: @BoazKG `strcat(book->title, title);` --> `strcpy(book->title, title);` or something else. because `book->title` isn't initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a hint, so I won't give you a complete solution:

The problem you are having is related to your two char fields in your struct,  *title* and *author*. They are pointers, not variables of a fixed size. That means that you need to allocate memory space for them. You will have to decide on an appropriate size for each, allocate the space for them, and then copy the text from the file into the allocated memory space. At the moment you are only allocating space for the pointers to the char fields.

Comment: That means the allocation needs to happen before I assign to them values with the read_file function right?

Comment: In construct_element, after you have allocated memory for the element, also allocate memory for the character strings that you want to store. You can consider that a general rule: if a struct has fields that do not have a fixed size, you need to allocate memory for the struct and for each of those dynamic fields.